# spring framework : expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

This super class DAO:

```
public class CrudDAO{

}
```

This child class:

```
@Repository
public class JnsTimeDao extends CrudDAO {

}

@Repository
public class BatchDAO extends CrudDAO {
}
```

this super service class

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public abstract class CrudService<D extends CrudDAO> {

    @Autowired
    protected D dao;
}
```

startup error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.gp.dao.CrudDAO] is defined: expected
>   single matching bean but found 2: batchDAO,jnsTimeDao

Comment: You have 2 beans of type `CrudDAO` one being `JnsTimeDao` and `BatchDao`. Hence Spring runtime is complaining of duplicate beans. You should ensure that Spring runtime will find either one of these as a qualified bean and wires it.

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 beans of type `CrudDAO`. So, Spring won't be able to understand which bean to inject. Can be solved as follows

```
@Repository("jnsTimeDao")
public class JnsTimeDao extends CrudDAO {

}

@Repository("batchDao")
public class BatchDAO extends CrudDAO {
}
```

While injecting use `@Qualifier`

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public abstract class CrudService<D extends CrudDAO> {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("batchDao")
        protected D dao;
    }
```

Comment: Please change @Transactional(readOnly = true) to @Transactional() as a default one

Comment: Although this is correct, using trait-oriented custom `Qualifier` would be better than those based on bean IDs.

Comment: CrudService   is super class

Comment: protected D dao;
is Equivocal